# Spyder keras module not found in windows 10

Tags: python, spyder

i am working a noob working on nerual nets using keras tensorflow etc i keep getting this error i tried installing the keras module over and over but keep getting the same error

**Code**

```
import keras
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<ipython-input-2-c74e2bd4ca71>", line 1, in <module>
     import keras 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

Comment: Looks like you need to install `keras`. You might want to google how to do that, shouldn't be very hard to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

In Spyder make sure you are in the working directory of the project you are working on (In terminal you normally cd your project) that means going inside your project. In Spyder on the Editor side,  click on the icon (*) and go to 'Set console working directory'. And start running your project again, it should work and clear the error.